# select sql query rows to column

Tags: sql, pivot

i have a select query leavetype and nofdays

```
leavetype   nofdays

sl           2
cl           2
pl           4
sl           3
cl           5
pl           6
```

i need select query with sum of noofdays in each row and select leavetype,cl,sl,pl
and final data should be in this form  given below:

```
Sl   Pl    Cl
5    10    7
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Read up on PIVOT / UNPIVOT

Comment: use sum and case statement

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: [Asked and answered many, many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+pivot)

Answer (score 1):

Do the `conditional` aggregation

```
select empid,
       sum(case when leavetype = 'sl' then nofdays else 0 end) as sl,
       sum(case when leavetype = 'pl' then nofdays else 0 end) as pl,
       sum(case when leavetype = 'cl' then nofdays else 0 end) as cl
from table t
group by empid;
```

Comment: if table have Unknown `leavetype` you cant write your code like this

Comment: i have column empid and i need data for each empid '

empid    leavetype   nofdays

     1              sl           2
       1              cl           2
     1                pl           4
      3               sl           3
       3              cl           5
       4              pl           6


empid   Sl   Pl    Cl
    1         2   2    0
  3       3    0    5

Comment: @MonikaRawat... use `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using SQL Server, not sure what DBMS you are using but the logic would be similar

Build the table:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (col1 varchar(2), col2 int)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
('sl',2),
('cl',2),
('pl',4),
('sl',3),
('cl',5),
('pl',6)
```

Pivot statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT col1,
           col2
    FROM @table
) p PIVOT(SUM(col2) FOR col1 IN([sl],
                                [cl],
                                [pl])) AS pvt;
```

returns:

```
sl  cl  pl
5   7   10
```

MS Docs for it are here :
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx